# Tint color on non-bar style segmented control

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uisegmentedcontrol

I've got a compilation issue with a UiSegmentedControl, whose style is bezeled. The colour is black. I get an error:

```
"Tint color on non-bar style segmented control"
```

Can this be solved, and is it an issue for app submission?

Comment: Can you please give some more detail ? I have used UISegmentedControl with style bezeled and tint color as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that's a bug in Xcode/Interface Builder.
The iOS HIG say nothing about the different styles and the documentation explicitly allows tint colors for bezeled UISegmentedControls:

> **UISegmentedControlStyleBezeled**
>   Segmented controls in this style can have a tint color.

I would just ignore the warning.

Comment: Which version are you using ? I execute the code on 4.3 simulator. it is working fine

Comment: There is no problem with the execution of the app. Interface Builder mistakenly shows a warning at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

In the interface builder, select the Segment control.

In the Attribute inspector,  Set the **Tint** to **Default**.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the XIB spouts this warning, but iOS indeed supports a tintColor with a bezeled style.  You can avoid the warning by specifying it programmatically.  There's a trick, though.  If the style is set to bezeled, setting the tintColor will be ignored.  You need to do it like this:

```
[segControl setSegmentedControlStyle:UISegmentedControlStyleBar];
segControl.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.48 alpha:1.0];
[segControl setSegmentedControlStyle:UISegmentedControlStyleBezeled];
```

In this case, I'm loading a XIB that has it set to bezeled (so I can see how it fits)...but I set it back to a bar and change the tint before setting it back.  Weird.